# DISCORDPY cant get message.reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello im trying to do a vote command but when i try to get the reaction list of the message, it gives me an empty list.

```
@bot.command()
async def mapvotetest(ctx):
    database_handler.set_has_voted(ctx.message.author.id,0)
    messagevote = "MAP VOTE : \n" # Message with emoji
    messagevote += " : bank \n"
    messagevote += " : frontiere\n" 
    messagevote += " : map test\n"
    test = await ctx.send(messagevote)
    await test.add_reaction("") # Add reaction
    await test.add_reaction("")
    await test.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.send(test.reactions)
```

if someone knows why...

Comment: Are you trying to catch all the reactions or just the reactions you added via bot?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem too and here is how i fixed it:

You have to **"reload" the message** to get the newest reactions because if you use [message.reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message.reactions) it returns the reaction list from the point when you defined your message

just fetch the message after that 5 seconds again with

```py
test = await test.channel.fetch_message(test.id)
```

and then you should get the reactions correctly.

would look something like this in your code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def mapvotetest(ctx):
    database_handler.set_has_voted(ctx.message.author.id,0)
    messagevote = "MAP VOTE : \n" # Message with emoji
    messagevote += " : bank \n"
    messagevote += " : frontiere\n" 
    messagevote += " : map test\n"
    test = await ctx.send(messagevote)
    await test.add_reaction("") # Add reaction
    await test.add_reaction("")
    await test.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    test = await test.channel.fetch_message(test.id)
    await ctx.send(test.reactions)
```

Comment: thanks, i found it ust after i asked ...